# using ajax and PHP to get json data from geojson

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm using the following php code to get data from geojson file and its working

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$data=file_get_contents("countries.geojson");
$data= json_decode($data, true);
$data2= $data["countries"]["country"];
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

echo json_encode($data2);
?>
```

I want to access this data in following ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/main.php",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

right now I'm getting error in console that means it is not getting data from the php code.
How shall I get that data from php file in this ajax call?

Comment: Use the Network tab to see what the PHP script is returning. There might be an error message.

Comment: php script is running fine and returning the data from json file

Comment: Then I can't think of any reason why you'd be getting an error in the JS. Are you sure there's nothing before or after the JSON in the response?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: If you look at the network tab again, what is the response code you get from the server? And when you said that the PHP script runs fine, did you mean when you made the ajax request, or that you've tested the script separately? Please be more specific and detailed when you answer to minimize the risk of misunderstandings.

Comment: Why not log the actual errors? `console.error(textStatus, errorThrown)`

Answer (score 0):

Try following code and look into console for response or error, returned data is not json formated as expected

```
    $.get('php/main.php',function(response){
        console.log(response);
        
    },'JSON').fail(function(xhr,ajaxOption,thrownError){
        console.error(xhr.responseText);
        console.error(thrownError);
    });
```